# Find values corresponding to conditions in other column, based on repeated occurence of names in rows

Tags: excel

UPDATE: I have now managed to make two columns, one to identify the condition, and one to identify the onset time of stim1. The only thing I now still need to do is to put the onset times for "same" in a separate column directly below each other. Somehow I can't manage to do that and chatgpt is not helping. These two columns look like this (columns Y and Z):

[image]

I have the following problem:

I need excel to identify control conditions, in which the dot number is 5x the same, and experimental conditions, in which the dot number is 5x different, from the Code column, which is column D in my sheet. You can see in the picture what it looks like. It then needs to retrieve the value in the Time column (column E in my sheet), corresponding to line stim1 and put it in column AZ for the control conditions, and column BB for the experimental conditions. They should be placed directly under each other. There should be 48 values for control and 48 values for experimental in the whole document.

!Sometimes the stim sequences are interrupted by a row containing 115, these should be ignored!

I have been fighting with ChatGPT the whole day to get it to work, using python, using macros etc, but it is not working because it does not understand the data structure. Is there somebody here that can save me? I basically just want the onset times for each condition.  Using the _con and _exp lines does not help, because these only occur in half of the trials. Thanks!!

Input from the Time column (E), based on the Code column (D):

[image]

Expected output to be put in columns AZ and BB, so the values from the Time column (column E) are pasted here, I colour coded for ease of understanding. This is just an example. There should in total be 48 of the green (control condition) and 48 of the yellow (experimental condition)

[image]

Here comes the table as Markdown table, hope that is how it should look:

| Code | Time |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| instruction_begin | -9584 |
| 1 | 170245 |
| mri_sync_1 | 170472 |
| 115 | 474806 |
| mri_sync_2 | 474952 |
| ITI | 476449 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 508269 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 518113 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 528280 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 538275 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 548113 |
| ITI | 564939 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot6.jpg | 584762 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot6.jpg | 594605 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot6.jpg | 604600 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot6.jpg | 614606 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot6.jpg | 624591 |
| resp_5:7_con_0 | 647599 |
| 115 | 654797 |
| 2 | 663871 |
| ITI | 665599 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot12.jpg | 691754 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot8.jpg | 701590 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot4.jpg | 711600 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot7.jpg | 721598 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot13.jpg | 731760 |
| resp_5:13_exp_1 | 749915 |
| 1 | 759301 |
| ITI | 761079 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot13.jpg | 776592 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot5.jpg | 786587 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot11.jpg | 796592 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 806573 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot2.jpg | 816590 |
| 115 | 834809 |
| resp_1:13_exp_1 | 839904 |
| 1 | 849163 |
| ITI | 850911 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot1.jpg | 878748 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 888738 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot12.jpg | 898738 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot6.jpg | 908748 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot8.jpg | 918734 |
| ITI | 935566 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot7.jpg | 965741 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot7.jpg | 975729 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot7.jpg | 985741 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot7.jpg | 995723 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot7.jpg | 1005734 |
| 115 | 1014806 |
| ITI | 1022566 |
| stim1_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot8.jpg | 1049232 |
| stim2_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot3.jpg | 1059232 |
| stim3_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot9.jpg | 1069231 |
| stim4_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot4.jpg | 1079224 |
| stim5_C:\Users\marius\Documents\PREDEX_svetlana\stimuli\Dot13.jpg | 1089228 |
| resp_5:14_exp_0 | 1107551 |

Comment: Can you post a copiable data using **[Mark-down_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** as well showing us the expected output

Comment: ^^^^ it may also be useful to include the expected outcome corresponding to the sample data

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added the expected outcome with colours to mark the corresponding values in the columns of origin. I'm trying to add the copiable data :)

Comment: Now I included the image as a table. Sometimes the stim rows are interrupted by a row containing 115, these are not in the example but they exist and need to be ignored by the code that will retrieve the data (otherwise it can't find all the sequences). Thanks!

Comment: Is there really nobody that can help with this? No AI model can solve this. There is some problem with the data format :(